# Excel API cell.insert taking a very long time to run

Tags: excel, office-js

I am trying to insert some rows within or below a used `range` from sheet.

Although my code here shows a hard-coded array, the data actually comes from a server application. I determine the order of inserts after scanning the server response.  My code works somewhat like below:

```js
Excel.run(function (ctx) {
    var rowIdsArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]; //data that might have come from server
    var sht = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
    for (var i = 50; i > 3; i--) {
        //I might want these rows to be inserted before rows
        //3 to 50. So 9 rows inserted 48 times
        for (var counter1 = 0; counter1 < rowIdsArray.length; counter1++) {
            var cell = sht.getUsedRange().getRow(parseInt(i)).getOffsetRange(1, 0);
            cell.insert();
        }
    }
    return ctx.sync().then(function () {
        console.log("rows inserted");
    });
}).catch(function (e) {
    console.log("Error Message is -> " + e.message);
});
```

I have `rowIdsArray` as array of rows with the `id` that I want to insert. The loop iterating explains at which index (in my project this array has random number) I want to add these rows into the sheet.

So I am basically inserting number of rows into the sheet (400-450 rows), but its taking way too much time. I can see Excel inserting rows *very* slowly, one by one.

Does office.js API provides any other way to achieve the same with very less time?

Answer (score 0):

You could set all the values at once:

```
Excel.run(function (ctx) { 
  var sheetName = "Sheet1";
  var rangeAddress = "A3";
  //values is:
  // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
  // [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  //...
  // [50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58]
  var values = (function(values){
    var i = -1;
    var rows = rows;
    ret = [];
    while(++i<rows){
      ret.push(
        values.map(
          function(value){
            return value+i;
          }
        )
      );
    }
  })([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
  var range = ctx.workbook
    .worksheets.getItem(sheetName)
    .getRange(rangeAddress)
    .getRowsBelow(rows)
    .getColumnsAfter(9);
  range.insert("Down");
  range.values = values;
  range.load('text');
  return ctx.sync().then(function() {
    console.log(range.text);
  });
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Error: " + error);
  if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
    console.log("Debug info: " + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
  }
});
```

I don't have excel so can't test it but that should do it.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i don't see this related to what i want to do. U given solution that can set values for the particular range, but i want to insert rows in given range. i don't see any insert option in your code. can u please elaborate more ?

Comment: @PavanDivekar I updated the answer to insert the range first then set the values (not sure if this would work because have no excel and am limited to MS documentation): https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/range#insertshift-string

Comment: you are right, but i am trying to insert rows in existing range that i already have, which cannot be done using code provided by you i suppose.

Comment: @PavanDivekar I don't know what you mean, can you update your question with a JSON example of the data you are trying to insert (only 3 rows will do)? Does every row in the data have the same amount of columns? The code in the answer may need to be: `range.insert("Down").values = values;`. That will insert 50 rows and move the 3rd row 50 rows down (I think).

Comment: An example of the sheet before/after might also help understand how it can be optimized.